# How will I get the active tab name in ngb-tabset on load of the component in angular?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I have used ngbTabset for tabs in my project. But I'm not able to get the active tab name in my console when the app gets loaded. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: add the code you tried with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

it's just ask about activeId -it your ngb-tab has id, return this value else a "random" name-. To get the ngbTab you can use ViewChild, you can also check the [API of ngb-tabset](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/api) to get other properties or methods

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vn3rlk?file=app/tabset-basic.ts)

```
  @ViewChild(NgbTabset,{static:false}) tabset
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    console.log(this.tabset.activeId)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML:
<div class="col-md-12">
  <ngb-tabset #t="ngbTabset" *ngIf="tabData" type="groups">
    <ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabData.groups" title={{tab.name}} >
        <div></div>
    </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>
</div>


TS:  


       export class MyTabs implements OnInit {   

          private tabSet: ViewContainerRef;    

          @ViewChild(NgbTabset) set content(content: ViewContainerRef) { 

            this.tabSet = content;  

          };
```